# Axiomatic system and symbolic, formal, mathematical language

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-language, philosophy-of-physics

Is there any need for axiomatic systems to be in a symbolic, formal, mathematical language?

Equivalently is there any prohibition of axioms in axiomatic systems being in natural language?

In other words is the existence of an axiom in a natural language sufficient to consider that set X is not an axiomatic system?

Euclids' Element had their axioms in the Greek language. It is still an axiomatic system.

Comment: What one can express in symbols can, in principle, be expressed in natural languages, after all, the use of symbols themselves is introduced using a natural language. Of course, the length of sentences needed to do it quickly becomes impractical, as one can see already with the verbosity of even relatively simple mathematics of antiquity and middle ages. Euclid's Elements is not axiomatic in the modern sense, its axioms are insufficient for its theorems and the gap is made up for by informal reasoning with diagrams, which also are a kind of symbolism.

Comment: Indeed. Whether using a natural or artificial language, the propositional content is largely recognized to be independent of the syntax. Concepts are to an extent pre-liguistic.